# help cleaning up var/lib/docker

Tags: 18.04, docker

I messed things up with docker on ubuntu 18.04 and now I have almost no space left on my disk.

- I tried to move var/lib/docker to /home and do a symbolic link in
  order to use some heavy images (nvidia tlt and nvidia digits), since I have /home on another partition.
- When things didn't work I removed the link and moved the folder back to
  where it belongs.
- It seems to me that when I tested if it worked, right before moving the folder back, ubuntu
  created the folder back, and when I did the movement things were strangely merged.

The problem now is what to do to get things back to normal (hopefully not reinstall ubuntu). I hope there are some redundant files that can just be deleted.

I had some other images that are not shown anymore with `sudo docker images`, but I have't remove either. Same goes to some containers

When I execute `sudo tree var/lib/docker > tree.txt` I get [This output](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1c3IoQ8u3bFW37D6GQamhpUpZf7xVTG_P/view?usp=sharing) (wich is 26.7 MB, ridiculously big, isn't it?)

---

Just checked and this folder's size is 24GB. The tlt image is 7, I assume the container might be the same, there are still almost 10 GB (25% of root disk) of salvageable space.

Any help would e really appreciated.
Thanks.

---

[This](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16OjRLaOKWUj5UNDA8lVo1GNvuaU7e3si/view?usp=sharing) is the tree after @Giorgos Saridakis's answer, now it's size is 20.2 MB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a risk and solved the issue.
I use the command `sudo tree --du -h /var/lib/docker > tree.txt` to see the folders sizes too and I found I had another 'docker' folder inside `/var/lib/docker/volumes`, which was 6.8 GB and had the same distribution as `/var/lib/doclker`.
After checking that a friend didn't had it, I just took the risk and did the following.

- sudo docker stop
- sudo mv /var/lib/docker/volumes/docker /path/to/an/external/drives/folder
- sudo docker start

It worked with no problem and after a reboot everything was looking ok, I can run the tlt image as usual.
Thank you all for your help, I know I was reckless, but I was also preparing to format my drive anyway, so I had nothing to lose (If you, future reader see this, be more careful than me).
Thanks you again!

Answer (score 5):

- do `service docker stop` before moving the folder
- if placing /var/lib/docker somewhere else, use a **bind** mount , e.g. `mount -o bind /external/disk/docker /var/lib/docker` , also "protect" the folder from files being written before mount with `chattr +i  /Var/lib/docker`
- it is always better to start your container again from a compose file or `docker pull` the image , since you might have messed up the overlay with your described steps
- folder size also comes from docker filesystems implementation , whereas filesystem is pulled as archive and then extracted
- 7GB is unlikely large for a docker image
- if you have large amount of  build cache / dangling images / stopped containers  `docker system prune -a` is your friend

Comment: This is in fact what I did for my Docker, I say good one!  Upvoted :)

Comment: Thanks, I followed some tuto over there, did the first point, but but it had no mention of the second.
Nvidia images are rediculously large (7.99 GB in fact).
I tried the prune, but got this:
Total reclaimed space: 0B
thanks for the idea :)